# Play audio in background AND respect Silent switch

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiosession

I want my audio to both play while the app is in the background, AND respect the Silence switch on the side of the phone. That is, the audio plays if the app is in the foreground or background, unless the switch is set to Silent. I also do not want to mix audio with other apps.

Some of the AVAudioSession categories give me one requirement, others give me another, but none seem to do everything I want. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

My UIBackground modes are audio, voip, and remote-notification.